# Estimating Equilibrium Price for Advertising using Simultaneous Equations Model

Tags: econometrics

I am attempting to build a simultaneous equations model that estimates the equilibrium price of display advertisement, but I have only seen textbook examples with Quantity being the dependent variable - this question is similar: [Equilibrium Price - OLS Regression](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/19077/equilibrium-price-ols-regression). However, I assume that quantity is also endogenous, and I think I should use two stage least squares to produce unbiased estimates. Display advertisement is bought/sold in online marketplaces, and that led me to believe this model would provide a good fit.

$P_{Dt} = \beta _{0} + \beta _{1} Q_{t} + \beta_{2} Visits + u_{t}$

$P_{St} = \alpha _{0} + \alpha _{1} Q_{t} + \alpha_{2} Print_{t} + \alpha_{3} Prod_{t} + u_{t}$

- $P_{Dt, St}$ = Inverse Demand and Inverse Supply
- $Q_{t}$ = Quantity of Display Advertisement
- $Visits$ = Index of web traffic/visits (akin to income effect)
- $Print$ = Price of print advertisement (substitution effect)
- $Prod$ = Creative production costs (factor of production)

If anyone has experience modeling structural equations with price as the dependent variable I would really appreciate hearing your thoughts on how I should create a predicted value for Quantity and finalize a reduced form equation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definately on the right track. What you are doing is estimating the inverse demand and inverse supply in your market. The variables ***Visits Print and Prod*** can be used as "shifters" i.e. instruments for the quantity in the equation in which they are not present. ***Visits*** can be used as an instrument for quantity, when estimating the inverse supply equation and ***Print and Prod*** can be used as instruments for quantity when estimationg the inverse demand equation.

A well known example of how this works is Grady's article on Fulton fish market. You can find STATA code that replicates that article here: https://www.stata.com/data/s4poe/chap11.do .

The data sets for the stata code are here: http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/poe4/data/stata/ .

Of course you should test the validity of the assumptions behind the use of IV in your SEM with the Hausman, Sargan-Wu and Stock-Yogo tests.