# Regression approximation for the rate of change in occupancy rate of residential market with respect to price

Tags: elasticity, regression, general-equilibrium

I have historical data on occupancy rates for a given neighborhood, along with characteristics and other local economic variables.

I am looking to estimate the regression equation with occupancy rates as dependent variable and price, level of supply, characteristics and economic vars as independent variables.

```
D(p) = Rent + Median Income + Supply + # of HH
```

- Median Income is time fixed effect.

My questions are:

1. How do you interpret the equilibrium price from the regression output? i.e price at which Occupancy rate is 100%. or price elasticity of demand.
2. Interaction term. Given that supply follows rental prices, add `supply * rent` as interaction term.
3. What other regression methods would make sense for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If the goal of the project is to model housing demand, I would suggest using the actual number of occupied housing units. Census data may calculate occupancy as an algebraic function of supply, that is, occupancy is derived *using* the supply variable. This may show up as a strong correlation in the model, but it doesn't capture the stochastic properties of housing demand.

2. If you are interested in the price elasticity of housing, just use a log-log regression. Here is a good post about [equilibrium price](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/19077/equilibrium-price-ols-regression).
3. What is the level of analysis? If you have panel data (historical data for $n$ neighborhoods), I would suggest looking into spatial regression.

For a given neighborhood $x$, the occupancy rate of the surrounding neighborhoods may affect demand for housing (the negative affects of vacancy "spill over" into $x$). Another example, if rent is high in the neighborhoods surrounding $x$,a shift in the demand for housing will occur, because people are making a spatial decision regarding where they will live and take into account the housing characteristics of the neighborhoods of a given area.  Therefore, to model housing demand, the occupancy rate and independent variables of surrounding neighborhoods may capture the process of housing demand in $x$.

This is refereed to as spatial dependence and it can affect the model a lot. I would recommend the software Geoda and GeodaSpace to analyze and run spatial regression models.

Comment: I like the idea of spatial regression. Are there any relevant links, papers you can share?

Comment: Anselin, Rey. (2014). Modern Spatial Econometrics in Practice: A Guide to GeoDa, GeoDaSpace and PySAL. That book is a mixture of statistics theory and also serves as a usuer manual for the open source software Geoda, GeodaSpace, and Pysal (a Python package). If you are interested in the heavier statistics theory I would recommend Anselin. (1988). Spatial Econometrics: Methods and Models. It basically laid the foundation for modern spatial econometrics.